# Spectrum of Wavelet

Tags: python, python-2.7, wavelet

I have a morlet wavelet which is described by a plane wave multiplied with a gaussian window, and a scaling parameter, s. I.e. in python language:

```
import numpy
f = 10
omega = 2*numpy.pi*f
x = numpy.linspace(-5,5,num=1000)
wavelet = numpy.exp(numpy.complex(0,1)*omega*x/s) * numpy.exp(-1.0*(x/s)**2/2.0)
```

Usually doubling the scaling parameter (also known as "level") of a wavelet halves its bandwidth. Plotting the FFT of the wavelet described above for different scales, `s = 2**i`, with i=1,2,3, ... the width is not halved for subsequent i.

Whats wrong with the morlet wavelet?

Comment: the first multiplicator scales with 1/s and the second with 1/(s**2), so you can not expect that the fft bandwidth behaves as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The above code that you have provided does not look (*to me*) as if it is properly constructing the Morlet wavelet. The paper [A Practical Guide to
Wavelet Analysis](http://paos.colorado.edu/research/wavelets/bams_79_01_0061.pdf) provides a great guide to the construction of Wavelet transforms and should provide an explanation to the effect of varying the wavelet scale.

Note, depending on your implementation, changing the wavelet scale will *not* update/change the scale of the FFT used to create the wavelet. Typically, the FFT is constructed, then it is used to construct the Descreet Wavelet Transform. Thus, changing the wavelet scale will not effect the underlying FFT.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But besides from the construction of the Wavelet Transform itself. Using a wavelet with a different scale should affect also its spectrum. So what do you mean with your last sentence?

Comment: Typically, you construct the FFT of your time-series first. This construction does not use the wavelet scale parameter. Thus, changing the wavelet scale cannot be expected to change the underlying FFT.

Comment: I didn't got it yet. What is the FFT of the time-series needed for?  As I use convolution for wavelet analysis I don't need FFT at all. I just use it for displaying the frequency components of each scaled wavelet. But here I wonder myself why subsequently scaled versions of the mother wavelet do not cover the hole spectrum as it is the case e.g. for bior3.5 wavelet.

Comment: To approximate the continuous wavelet transform,
the convolution (2) should be done N times for each
scale, where N is the number of points in the time series. (The choice of doing all N convolutions
is arbitrary, and one could choose a smaller
number, say by skipping every other point in n.) By
choosing N points, the convolution theorem allows us
do all N convolutions simultaneously in Fourier space
using a discrete Fourier transform (DFT). This is why using an FFT is to perform these convolutions is much more efficient for large sets.

Comment: Although you are not using the FFT, my point still stands, your calculations of the convolutions will not contain any reference to the wavelet scale. Thus to answer your question, there may be nothing wrong with the Morlet wavelet, but you cannot expect to see any variation in the plotted value of the series convolution or FFT by varying the wavelet scale...